# Pseudoinverse system of linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, pseudoinverse

$Ax = b$ describes a convex polyhedron, where $A$ is a real matrix and $b$ is a real vector.
Now assume $A$ has less rows than columns.

If you take a look here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Matrix_solution

The formula 
$$
x = Pb + (I-PA)w
$$

where $P$ is the pseudoinverse produces all solutions. So every point inside the polyhedron.

But what I don't understand is:

The polyhedron could be bounded, but I have the feeling with a certain value of $w$ I can produce as big $x$ as I want since $Pb$ is a constant and $(I-PA)$ is also a constant matrix.

Could someone explain how to understand this formula?

Answer (score 0):

$Ax = b$ describes an affine subspace, that is a point or an unbounded polyhedron. In the latter case, there is no problem, in the further case, we have that $PA = {\rm Id}$ (otherwise we had more than one solution), so $x = Pb$ is the only point.

If you want to consider all polyhedra, you have to look at $Ax \le b$.

Comment: yes but you can Ax <= b bring to standard form and then you have A'y   = b

Comment: I assume that by "bring to standard form" you introduce slack variables. But if that is the case then $A'y=b$ is *not* the only constraint; there are non-negativity constraints on the slack variables you introduced. So @martini is right here.

Comment: **And** $y \ge 0$ (in standard form). There are no bounded affine subspaces beside points!

Comment: but with the y >= 0 constraints i am bounded?

Comment: You can be bounded, yes. Think of two dimensions (to *see* things), then $ax_1 + bx_2 = c$ is a line (or the empty set), but its intersection with $x_1\ge 0$, $x_2 \ge 0$ is a ray or a *bounded* segment.

Comment: and can you transform the formula to consider y >= 0?